# Extracting the month value from date field array

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with two columns of dates when a customer expressed interest in buying an item and a column of dates when the sale was actually made. I am trying to sum the total amount of sales when the month on the interest matches the month of the sale. For example:

```
    Date of Interest     Date of sale   Price
       04/15/2015          04/15/2015    $4,795
       04/09/2015          04/27/2015    $3,596
       03/31/2015          04/22/2015    $6,477
       04/16/2015          04/28/2015    $9,755
```

The formula I am trying to use is this

```
=SUMIFS(E2:E15,MONTH(C2:C15),H2,MONTH(F2:F15),H2)
```

Where `E2:E15` is the column of sales amount

- `C2:C15` is the date of interest
- `F2:F15` is the column of date of sale
- `H2` is a field that contains a month number (4 for this example)

If the formula worked, it should return a value of `$18,146` (the sale of `$6,477` would not included as the interest date was in month 3)

However, I get an error with the formula (no specific information).  Is there anyway to extract the month number from both columns within this formula?  I can create additional columns that have the month number and if I use them the formula works.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

[image: 1]

Comment: Thank you everyone for the excellent suggestions.  Especially you Ron, that solution worked great.  Bill.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Lead_date) = MONTH(Sold_Date))*Sold_Amt)
```

or:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Date_of_Interest)= MONTH(Date_of_sale))*Price)
```

If you want to restrict your answer to the month number contained in H2, as suggested by @user3578951, then simply modify the above to add that factor:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(Date_of_Interest)= MONTH(Date_of_sale))*(MONTH(Date_of_Interest)=H2)*Price)
```

Comment: With this one, it'll check if any months are equal and then return the total sum.  If he only wants to check if "March" matches both columns, then return only March, this will still return $18,146 so just be aware.

Comment: @user3578951 I interpret his question differently:  `I am trying to sum the total amount of sales when the month on the interest matches the month of the sale`  So, as he writes, it will sum if March is the month of both; or if Apr is the month of both; but not if March is one and Apr is the other.  However, I will add an addendum to the formula to allow him to pick a specific month.  Thanks.

Comment: Fosenfeld - Ah, yes that makes sense, I read it the same (both) ways.

Comment: Thank you so much Ron, the last formula worked a treat.  Much appreciated.  Also thank you to the other responders.

Comment: @user2278537 Since it worked for you, if you could mark my response as the answer, I would appreciate it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a helper column to create a column of months (in number form), you can use your formula.  Just insert a column next to your two date columns, and use `=Month(C2)` and drag down.  Then you can just use `=sumifs(e2:e100,_[lead date helper month range]_,h2,_[sold date helper month range]_,h2)`.